# Mac m1 node ffi-napi throw error "no suitable image found." and " mach-o, but wrong architecture"

Tags: javascript, rust, ffi, apple-m1

rust code is(lib.rs):

```rust
///
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn fib(n: i64) -> i64 {
  return match n {
    1 | 2 => 1,
    n => fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
  }
}
```

build this cargo project with:

```sh
cargo build
```

js code is(index.js):

```
var ffi = require('ffi-napi');
const isWin = /^win/.test(process.platform)

const rust = ffi.Library('target/debug/' + (!isWin ? 'lib' : '') + 'ffi', {
  fib: ['int', ['int']]
})

function fib(n) {
  if (n === 1 || n === 2) {
    return 1
  }
  return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
}

// js
console.time('node')
console.log(fib(40))
console.timeEnd('node')

// rust
console.time('rust')
console.log(rust.fib(40))
console.timeEnd('rust')
```

execute the js code in node:

```sh
node index.js
```

but got error:

```
/Users/yongchun/workspace/js/ffi-demo/node_modules/ffi-napi/lib/dynamic_library.js:75
    throw new Error('Dynamic Linking Error: ' + err);
    ^

Error: Dynamic Linking Error: dlopen(target/debug/libffi.dylib, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    target/debug/libffi.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/yongchun/workspace/js/ffi-demo/target/debug/libffi.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    at new DynamicLibrary (/Users/yongchun/workspace/js/ffi-demo/node_modules/ffi-napi/lib/dynamic_library.js:75:11)
    at Object.Library (/Users/yongchun/workspace/js/ffi-demo/node_modules/ffi-napi/lib/library.js:47:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yongchun/workspace/js/ffi-demo/index.js:4:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

Comment: Are you running the x86 or ARM version of Node? What is `process.arch`? Maybe your library doesn't match? Or maybe `ffi-napi` didn't compile for the right Node version?

Comment: I switch to node `v12.22.6`, this problem seems to be solve!

Comment: I build   Universal binary with two architecture  arm64 , x86_64  for TDengine libtaos.so .and use node v12.22.6 solves my problem.